# Environment variables not found in python code

Tags: python, linux, linux-mint

I want to install chromedrivers with chromedriver_autoinstaller in python on my Mint Linux.
I use the example code from chromedriver_autoinstaller:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_autoinstaller


chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()  # Check if the current version of chromedriver exists
                                      # and if it doesn't exist, download it automatically,
                                      # then add chromedriver to path

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError: No chrome executable found on PATH
```

Chrome is installed and the command google-chrome works in a termin. What I did is:

1. create /etc/profile.d/google-chrome.sh
2. add export PATH="/usr/bin/google-chrome:$PATH" to the file
3. restart computer

The error already appears. Do you understand why I get this error and what I can do?

Answer (score 1):

Just this code works in the latest version of Selenium. There is no need for an auto-installer.

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
```

Comment: In this case I get the error message "selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH.". I don't understand the error message because I don't want to download the chrome driver manually and add it to the PATH. The reason is my code runs on a server and sometimes the server gets some updates (for google-chrome too). Then the system should continue to work with a new chromedriver without any manual work.

Comment: It seems like your selenium is not updated. Use `pip install -U selenium` to get the updated version of selenium i.e. `4.10.0`.