# Chrome not found by the selenium

Tags: python, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver

I wrote a Python script that has been working for over a year. Recently it stopped working since it doesn't find chromium at all, the terminal keeps showing this

```
/bin/sh: 1: google-chrome: not found
/bin/sh: 1: google-chrome-stable: not found
/bin/sh: 1: google-chrome-beta: not found
/bin/sh: 1: google-chrome-dev: not found
```

The latest version of the browser is installed in its usual path 'usr/bin/chromium-browser' and I also have the latest driver version, here's the part of the script that should open a Chrome window and goes to its designated URL:

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver_path = './chromedriver'
url = [URL]
loginid=input("id: ")
loginpass=input("password: ")
options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element(By.ID, "loginid").send_keys(loginid)
driver.find_element(By.ID, "loginpass").send_keys(loginpass)
```

what should I update?

Comment: have you tried manually downloading it?

Comment: Check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76752843/7598774

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Environment variables not found in python code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76906487/environment-variables-not-found-in-python-code)

Answer (score -1):

- You have to switch to version, `version='114.0.5735.90'`.

  `driver=webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager(version='114.0.5735.90').install())`
- it's because https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads only goes up to version 114.
- OR Update your selenium and checkout the solution [There is no such driver by URL https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_115.0.5790 error with Python webdrivermanager & Chrome 115.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76724939/there-is-no-such-driver-by-url-https-chromedriver-storage-googleapis-com-lates)

Edit:

- The latest release "Selenium 2.0" is integrated with WebDriver API.

Comment: it throws exception...
 __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'version'

Comment: @M.Mariscal in newer versions of Selenium, You don't need Version or even the Drivers; Selenium will take care of  everything itself.